# Having trouble with this NSURL method

Tags: objective-c

Can anybody tell me excatly how I should execute this method on an NSURL object?

```
URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath
```

Compiler says that the method can't be found when I execute it.

Thanks a lot.

This is where I am trying to implement the code:

```
- (void)data
{
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: [[user data] objectAtIndex: 5]];
NSURL * url2 = [[NSURL alloc] init];
url2 = [url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath];

NSData *newImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url2];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:newImage];

imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;

[imageView setImage:image];

[user autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Please show your code where you try to execute the method for better responses.

Comment: According to help it's simple instance method. Did you use it on class instead?

Comment: Also, is this for iOS or MacOSX?  Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have NSURL named something like myURLWithSymlinks, you would do something like:

```
NSURL * myURLWithoutSymlinks = [myURLWithSymlinks URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
```

Note that according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW32),  `URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath` is only  available in iOS4.0 or above and MacOSX 10.6.  If you are using an older version of iOS (or MacOSX), that could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I just get: 'NSURL' may not respond to -URLByResolvingSymlinkInPath. I'm running 10.6.4 btw.

Comment: You may be _running_ on 10.6 but what OS are you _targeting_ when you build your app?